# How can I decrypt below functions string with Rfc2898DeriveBytes?

Tags: c#, cryptography, encryption

How can I decrypt string that is encrypted with below function?

```
private static byte[] salt = new byte[] { 23, 21, 32, 33, 46, 59, 60, 74 };
private static int iterations = 1000;
private static int cb = 32;

public static string GetEncrypt(string plainText)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes k = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(plainText, salt, iterations);
    byte[] data = k.GetBytes(cb);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

Comment: as a side-note: a constant is no proper salt. A salt should be different for each key derivation.

Answer (score 9):

You can't. You've misunderstood the purpose of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. It's not meant to be an reversible encryption algorithm - it's just meant to be a way of deriving a *key* which you then use within another encryption algorithm.

The idea is that you ask for a password, convert it (with a salt) into an encryption key, and use that key to encrypt the data (e.g. with `TripleDES`).

Then later, you ask for the password again, use the same salt to generate the same key, and then you can use that to decrypt the encrypted data.

Read [RFC 2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) for more information.

Comment: Hi Jon thanks for the reply. Can you please give me example if you can for the same as I am not very aware of cryptography?

Comment: @TusharMaru: There's an example if you read the documentation for `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`

Comment: I could not found can you please help me?

Comment: @TusharMaru: What could you not find? The documentation for the class? JUst search for "msdn Rfc2898DeriveBytes" and you'll get there straight away - the example is at the bottom.

Comment: okay I got that in MSDN but what should I set as password parameter? As my question in above method "GetEncrypt" password parameter is plainText but that is different every time so I could not do the decrypt?

Comment: You can see the source of Stack Exchange OpenID Provider for a real-world example using Rfc2898DeriveBytes: https://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs#1265

Comment: @Tushar: If you provide a different password, how do you expect to decrypt the data? The whole point of a password is that that is what is used to protect the data.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your reply. So password needs to be same every time? above function is correct or not? Should I decrypt the data that encrypted through the above function?

Comment: @TusharMaru: No, your current method is not an *encryption* method at all. I think you need to start from scratch and read a good tutorial or book on encryption.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Tuple<string, string, string> Encrypt(string encryptText)
    {
        byte[] bytesBuff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptText);
        string keyValue;
        string vectorValue;

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            var crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptText, saltSize, iterations);
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);

            using var mStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                cStream.Close();
            }

            encryptText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
            keyValue = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
            vectorValue = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV);
        }

        return new Tuple<string, string, string>(encryptText, keyValue, vectorValue);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string decriptText, string keyValue, string vectorValue)
    {
        decriptText = decriptText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] bytesBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(decriptText);

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(keyValue);
            aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(vectorValue);

            using var mStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                cStream.Close();
            }

            decriptText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
        }

        return decriptText;
    }
```

Comment: Encryt & Decrypt functions using Rfc2898DeriveBytes, sample usage : saltSize = 256 and iterations = 1000. By my side, I store the encrypted password and its relative Key and Vector generated as string values into an SQLite table, that are used as input parameters of the Decrypt function.